# Python: How to read a directory of texts into a list

Tags: python

I am trying to work with `gensim` for topic modeling. From what I can tell looking at the module's documentation, `gensim` expects to receive its input as a list, with each item in a list being a text:

```
documents = ["Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications",
        "A survey of user opinion of computer system response time",
        "The EPS user interface management system"]
```

I have a collection of texts in a directory that I would like to use with `gensim`, and so I need to read those files into a list. Each of those texts, some of which consist of multiple lines -- the texts range in size from a little under 100 words to a little over 1000 words -- needs to be one item in the list. If stripping newlines out is required, I think I can figure out how to do that, but embedding it into a loop is where I fail ... completely. (In fact, I am taking myself to loop school over the weekend, but I regularly mess that part up.)

I have found all kinds of useful information on how to read a single file into a list -- by line or by word or by whatever -- but I can't figure out how to read a series of text files into a series of strings all contained within a single list -- this is the important bit:

```
textfile1.txt
textfile2.txt
```

need to become

```
list = ['contents of textfile1', 'contents of textfile2']
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
# get to the files, open an empty list

import glob

file_list = glob.glob('./texts' + '/*.txt')
documents = []

# Now to read the files into a list:

for file in file_list:
    documents.append()

print documents
```

The `print documents` is obviously a throwaway line so I could check my work, and you can see that I didn't get very far with the loop.

Comment: Are the strings in `documents` intended to be filenames with the extension removed?

Comment: Well, each `file_path` is the pathname to a file you want to read. So the `with open(…)` has to be `with open(file_path)`. Which obviously means you've got the structure wrong: the `with` has to come inside the `for` loop, not before it.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you know how to read a single file into a list, write that code inside the `with` statement, then we can show you how to concatenate those lists together. (Hint: it's the `extend` method, or the `+=` operator.)

Comment: Well, my first lesson here is not to post in the evening when, apparently, I'm too tired to write a sensible question. So, first, a big thank you to both [TigerHawkT3](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2617068/tigerhawkt3) and to [abarnet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert) for deciphering as much of my obtuse question as they did. I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for clarifying the question. I've edited my answer - hopefully it helps.

Comment: Both of these answers are amazing. Thank you both for taking time out not only to help but also to teach. I've given you both points. And, [TigerhawkT3](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2617068/tigerhawkt3), the next task on my list was to run some clean up on these files, so the `.replace()` method chained into the process was just the right tip. (Can one do multiple replaces, e.g. to get rid of tabs (`\t`) while I'm at it? Eventually, I'm going to be working with some XML documents, and it would be nice to strip here and not have to pre-process the files. That's eventually. Not now.)

Comment: I also find the two different ways of constructing the `for` loop fascinating. [abarnert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert) uses: `for file_path in file_list:    with open(file_path) as f:` and [TigerhawkT3](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2617068/tigerhawkt3) uses: `for filename in file_list:    with open(filename, 'r') as f:`

Comment: Yes, you can chain as many methods as you like. `'hello'.replace('h','1').replace('e','2')` will `return` the string `'12llo'`. The two constructs you mentioned are the same - we just used different variable names, and I specified read mode (`'r'`) instead of letting it default to that.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it works. But, with the two of your prompting me to think more clearly, I also see that chaining a string of `replace` methods would get ugly fast. I think I'm going to try to do the clean-up in the next part of the script. Again, many thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with` isn't a loop. It only runs the contained code once. In this context, it guarantees that the opened file will be closed once the `with` block ends, even if there's an error.

One way to look through all the text files in a directory is with `os.listdir()`:

```
import os

documents = []

for f in os.listdir():
    if f[-4:] == '.txt':
        documents.append(f[:-4])
```

Or as a comprehension:

```
documents = [f[:-4] for f in os.listdir() if f[-4:] == '.txt']
```

You will then have a `list` called `documents` containing the names of the files in the (current working) directory. For example, a folder containing the files `hello.txt` and `world.txt` will result in `documents` containing the strings `'hello'` and `'world'`.

Remember, after you've done that, you'll need to open the files. The `with` construct is recommended.

```
contents = []
for document in documents:
    with open(document+'.txt', 'r') as f:
        contents.append(f)
```

This will result in a `list` of `contents`. Each element is a `file` object, which can be iterated over line by line or processed in some other way (like `contents[0] = contents[0].read()` to replace that `file` object with a string containing the file's contents). No comprehension for this one due to the `with` construct.

---

To answer your edited question (which does seem more reasonable than the original), you can create a `list` of the string contents of each of a folder's text files as follows:

```
import glob

file_list = glob.glob('./texts' + '/*.txt')

# create document list:
documents = []
for filename in file_list:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        documents.append(f.read()) # option 1, to get a direct string
        # documents.append(f.readlines()) # option 2, to get a list of lines
        # documents.append([item.strip() for item in f.readlines()]) # option 3, to get a list of lines with no linefeeds
        # documents.append(f.read().replace('\n', ' ') # option 4, to get a direct string, linefeeds replaced with spaces
```

Assuming a directory `texts` in your current working directory with file `first.txt` containing `'hello\nworld'` and file `second.txt` containing `'hi\npeople'`, each of those four options will create a different result for `documents`, represented as follows (each statement would make a `list` equivalent to its corresponding option):

1. `documents = ['hello\nworld', 'hi\npeople']`
2. `documents = [['hello\n', 'world'], ['hi\n', 'people']]`
3. `documents = [['hello', 'world'], ['hi', 'people']]`
4. `documents = ['hello world', 'hi people']`

Comment: He's already using `glob.glob`; he doesn't need `os.listdir` too.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `glob.glob`, so I used `os.listdir()` instead. It would be nice to see an answer with `glob.glob` as well.

Comment: His question is already a good example of `glob`… except for the part about not opening each file that he finds.

Answer (score 2):

First, you obviously don't know what to put in the `with open...`. Well, what you want to open is *each `*.txt` file*. You've already got that, as each `file_path`, inside the loop. So, you have to move the `with open` inside the loop to open each file. (As [TigerhawkT3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30115070/908494) explains, `with` isn't a loop—making sure the file gets closed is all it does.)

Next, you need to do something to *read* each file. You say you already know how to read a single file in the way you want, so I won't explain that, and I'll just use the simplest thing (the file itself, which is an iterable of the lines, with the newlines still on).

Finally, you want to concatenate all the lists together into one big flat list. You've *almost* got that with the `documents.append`, but you want `extend` here. `append` is for adding one element to a list; `extend` is for adding all of the elements from another iterable.

So, putting it together:

```
import glob

file_list = glob.glob('./texts' + '/*.txt')
documents = []

for file_path in file_list:
    with open(file_path) as f:
        documents.extend(f)

print documents
```

---

While this is what you originally asked for, it apparently isn't what you wanted. You want the contents of each file as one giant string. That's just as easy. `f.read()` reads the contents of the file as one giant string. Of course now you want `append`, rather than `extend`, because you have just one new thing to add instead of a list of them. So:

```
import glob

file_list = glob.glob('./texts' + '/*.txt')
documents = []

for file_path in file_list:
    with open(file_path) as f:
        documents.append(f.read())

print documents
```

---

Really, once you know how to read a single file in whatever format you wanted (one big string, a list of strings for each line, a list of rows for each line that are themselves lists of words or CSV columns, …), doing the same over multiple files is just taking that code and wrapping it up in a loop that stores the results with `list.append` or `list.extend` (or, at worst, something like `dict[key]=value` or `dict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)`). It's all pretty easy.

Comment: First, thank you for taking the time to answer the question and also to write an answer that explains so much. The explanations help *a lot*. This works, except it turns each line in a text into an item in the list. Is there a way to have the entire contents of a text file become one item in a list?