# Reading the contents of several files into a list in Python

Tags: python, list, file

I have a shell script which pipes the files of a certain directory into a file titled `"list.txt"`.
I am trying to write a python script that reads in the names of the files inside `list.txt`, opens them, and saves their contents to a list. Each file inside of `list.txt` contains two numbers on two different lines. So far, I have been able to read in the files of the names of the files in the directory, however I keep getting an error when trying to read in the contents of the files:

`IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Below is the code I have written so far:

```
f = open("list.txt")
file = f.readlines()
f.close()
del file[0]
del file[0]
file = [w.replace('\n','') for w in file]
#print file

length_file = len(file)
data = []

for i in range(0,1):
        fa = open(file[i])
#       print fa
        data[i] = fa.read()
        fa.close()
        data[i] = [t.replace('\n','') for t in data]
#print i
#print data
#print data[1]
```

The error occurs on the line `data[i] = fa.read()` statement.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check how big `file` is and how big `i` is

Comment: Do you understand what the error is telling you?

Comment: the length of file is equal to the number of file names that are in list.txt, which is 94 files. I remove the first two file names in lines 4 and 5 because they contain irrelevant information.

Comment: I would like `data[i]` to contain the contents inside of `file[i]`.

Comment: Blorgbeard, I understand what the error is for, I just don't understand why I am getting it.

Comment: Are you sure the error occur at line `fa = open(file[i])` (given your comment that you are sure `len(file) == 92` by the time you get to the loop is absolutely correct)? Your code looks like it'll get that very same error at line `data[i] = [t.replace(...` i.e. a few lines down

Comment: Tuan333, I'm sorry, the error occurs at `data[i] = fa.read()` , and yes if I remove `[i]` the code will work, but it throws the same error at `data[i] = [t.replace(...` . If i remove `[i]` on this line as well, the code will work, but at the end of the for loop `data` only contains contains of the last file in `list.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Getting this error

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

When trying to access at element means that the location in the list does not exist.

Since your range is setup to have only an index of 0, that means that file is empty when you try to call it.

I assume it has something to do with this deleting the entries in file before you try to call them further down in that for loop, but cannot be sure:

```
del file[0]
del file[0]
```

What you can do to check is print file in that loop.  Also, it is more idiomatic to setup a for loop using readlines like this:

```
f = open('yourfile.txt','r')
for line in f.readlines():
    # do something
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am still having issues with my code. I use `del file[0]` twice because I want to remove the first two files in `file` because they do not contain useful information. I have printed file to the command line, and it contains the files I wish to open. I have also tried removing `del file[0]` but I still get the same error.

Comment: np.  last idea before I go to sleep.  just above that for loop, do this print(file[0])    Do you get the error?

Comment: i printed it just before the for loop and it contains the first filename that i want to open.

Comment: I just noticed that the error was actually in a different line.  The error occurs on the line data[i] = fa.read() statement.  when you change something substantial like this, it is customary to put EDIT: with the edit after in the main text of your question so that everyone can see (and not waste time, for example print(file[0]) is not what I would have suggested if I saw that you changed where the error originated.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm still pretty new to this website, but I'll keep that in mind next time I make an edit. Do you have any suggestions as to what could be the cause of the error with the error being in `data[i] = fa.read()` ? Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After further research, I have found a solution that reads in the contents of each of my files, and stores both values in the file as an entry in `data` using this thread:

[Python: How to read a directory of texts into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114934/python-how-to-read-a-directory-of-texts-into-a-list)

My edited code:

```
with open("list.txt") as f:
        file = f.readlines()
f.close()

del file[0]
del file[0]

file = [w.replace('\n','') for w in file]

length_file = len(file)
data = []

for i in range(0, length_file):
        with open(file[i]) as fa:
                data.append(fa.read())
        fa.close()
        data = [t.replace('\n','') for t in data]
#print data[0], data[1]
```

****EDIT****

I now have the code functioning as needed. For others who might need to make a list of lists:

This code reads in the file names of a directory stored in `list.txt`. It loops through, opens each file by filename and saves the two values inside of the file to the variable `data`. `data` contains a list of lists.

```
    with open("list.txt") as f:
        file = f.readlines()
f.close()

del file[0]  #in my case removes the first two files in list.txt because they contain irrelevant info 
del file[0]

file = [w.replace('\n','') for w in file]

length_file = len(file)
data = []

for i in range(0, length_file):
        with open(file[i]) as fa:
                data.append(fa.read().split('\n'))
        fa.close()
print data[0]
print data
```

For example in this code:

`data[0] = [value1 of file1 from list.txt, value2 of file1 from list.txt]` and `data = [[value1 of file 1 from list.txt , value2 of file1 from list.txt], [value1 of file2 from list.txt, value2 of file 2 from list.txt], ...etc.`